# H2 and MySQL compatibility issues

Tags: mysql, sql, testing, h2, liquibase

i am using H2 for my integration tests with Liquibase and it seems that there are compatibility issues.

A simple change column function does not pass on H2 where it works perfectly on MySQL distribution.

here is the query:

> ```
> ALTER TABLE `designs`
> ALTER COLUMN `description` `description` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `created`;
> ```

And the error:

> ```
> 2014-06-07 14:27:05,708 [DEBUG] [NewPooledConnection,handleThrowable(),430] - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@78af2ac3 handling a throwable.
> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE DESIGNS 
> ALTER COLUMN DESCRIPTION TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER[*] CREATED "; SQL statement:
> ALTER TABLE designs ALTER COLUMN description TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER created [42000-178]
> at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344)
> ```

Some configuration:

> ```
> repository.connectionString = jdbc:h2:mem:db;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
> repository.driver = org.h2.Driver
> repository.username = sa
> repository.password =
> ```

Any ideas how to tackle this? as far as i understand H2 should be compatible with Mysql

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[As](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#compatibility) [documented](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility), H2 is (up to a certain point) compatible to other databases such as HSQLDB, MySQL and PostgreSQL. But there are certain areas where H2 is incompatible.

See also the [SQL syntax supported by H2](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html).